# Allow HTML in Excerpts in Elementor

Tags: plugins, excerpt

Is there any way to display formatted text from Elementor in the excerpts. If it's not possible, it would be great when the formatted excerpts with activated Elementor plugin would be displayed.

I looked trough a lot of articles, but nothing works with page builders.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask Elementor's support about.